# Rust Postgres (synchronous) driver called from async main causes "Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime"

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio

I have a project where I need to use the postgres synchronous driver (the third-party library wants sync callbacks) and it exposes a GRPC API.

Unfortunately, rust-postgres does a `block_on` which is nested with `#[tokio::main]`

The minimal repro would be:

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _client = Client::connect("host=localhost dbname=template1 user=postgres", NoTls).unwrap();
}
```

with the dependencies:

```
tokio = { version = "1.6.1", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
postgres = "0.19.1"
```

I get the error:

```
'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.'
```

Performance of the SQL queries is not critical, I am fine blocking on them. I'd rather not switch to `tokio-postgres` since it would mean rewrapping everything as synchronous again.

Comment: Why are you using `#[tokio::main]` if you intend to only use the sync driver? Presumably, that causes your problem.

Comment: This is just a minimal example. The real code uses Tonic which needs a Tokio runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn the `rust-postgres` code onto its own independent thread.

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let _client = Client::connect("host=localhost dbname=template1 user=postgres", NoTls).unwrap();
    });
}
```

Then set up inter-thread communication via standard methods, e.g. `tokio::sync::mpsc` message passing, to get data between the database driver and the rest of your Rust code.

Stuff as much client and error handling as possible into the new thread to limit talking across threads, in case that ever presents a performance bottleneck.